# Avoid automatic checkout of documents when using required fields

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, check-out

We are using SharePoint 2013 on premises. We have a document library that uses managed content type, it has the option to NO check out documents and it doesn't use versions, although I have tried with using major versions and it didn't make any difference.

Our problem is that one of the content types has a required field. When that option is on, the documents are kept checked out automatically even if the library is set to no check out documents. If we made the required field not required, the problem disappears, however, we would like that it is required.

The files remain checked out even if the required field is filled in. If we set a default value for the required column the problem also disappears but that is not ideal because then the user uploads the document without thinking about what value to put in the metadata.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Validation settings at library level and keep the Required settings of the content type column optional.

Example validation setting on the "Title" column.

[image]

The validation message would appear on the forms.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it does not show the columns I want to make required on the "Insert Column" section. The columns that I want to make required use managed metadata, I am not sure if it is for this reason that it is not appearing here?

Comment: I tried to add it in the formula even it was not offer on the column sections and I got the following error confirming what I thought before:"Sorry, something went wrong 
One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas. 

"

Comment: @Tess Validation setting for Managed Metadata column is not available. So this validation can't be used. Create a new library, add same content type and see if this issue comes again. This helps to isolate if it is a library specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set a default value (such as NOT DEFINED) , but it bypass the "required" configuration. Discuss with you user, this option can be usefull to remind people to fill something when they know the information

Comment: Hi, I know if I put a default value it bypass the required configuration, but it is not ideal, although the idea of using a value as NOT DEFINED is good. It seems strange to me that the document is kept required even when you complete the required fields, it seems to me a bug in sharepoint?